# PHP cannot read cookie from same page

Tags: php, html, firefox, cookies

Hey guys i created a simple PHP page to  set a cookie and after reloading  check if the cookie is existing and echo out its content.

Setting the cookie works. Reloading works. Displaying the cookie works.
BUT: If I leave the page (go to another url etc.) and come back again, the page can NOT read the cookie which was set before, although the cookie hasn't expired and firefox says it's still existing.

Code of the php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title>Authentication cookie</title>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Authentication code: <input type="text" name="authcode" value="<?php echo $_GET["authcode"]; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form><br>



<?php
$cookie_name = "authpi";
$cookie_value = $_POST["authcode"];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '10.0.0.2'); // 86400 = 1 day

 ?>


<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["authpi"])) {
     echo "Authentication Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
        #header("Location: http://www.google.at/");
} else {
     echo "Authentication Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Your authentication code is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

 <p><strong>Note:</strong> After setting the Cookie reload the page to make sure it works!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT: Tried to explain my problem better.

Comment: Explained it again. I read the other question but my problem is not the one mentioned there. Please reopen.

Comment: It is no duplicate, if you read it you will understand. Please reopen the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` is set when the page loads after setting it  so If you want immediate access, you can set `$_COOKIE['variable']` direct.

so do like this

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '10.0.0.2'); // 86400 = 1 day
if(!isset($_COOKIE["authpi"]){
$_COOKIE[authpi] = $cookie_value;}
```

Comment: Setting the cookie is no problem, setting its value also. It's ok that the value is only available and displayed after a reload, no problem.

The problem is that after reloading TWO times, the cookie does NOT get recognised by the page, also if i leave the page and open it again the cookie is not read and displayed by the page!